# Help to draw a simple Dynkin diagram either with dynkin-diagrams or tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzlibrary

I have some troubles drawing a Dynkin diagram as I want to. I produced the following code. But it does not do what I want to do.

```
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[edge length=2cm, edge/.style={ultra thick}, root radius=.2cm]{A}{o.ooo}
\node[below=.2cm] at (root 3) {$\beta\perp\alpha+\gamma$}; 
\node[below=.2cm] at (root 4) {$\gamma$}; 
\end{dynkinDiagram}
```

I list some problems: (1) The circles around the nodes are not `ultra thick`. (2) The dashed line between `(root 1)` and `(root 2)` is not `ultra thick` either. (3) The labels at `(root 3)` and `(root 4)` are not horizontally aligned. (4) I want to produce a brace over `(root 1)` to `(root 2)` (labelled `$\alpha'$`) as well as a brace over `(root 1)` to `(root 3)` (labelled `$\alpha$`), and I tried `\dynkinBrace` or `\dynkinBrace*` for it which produced a fatal error and stopped compiling.

I would be happy to use `tikz` instead of the package `dynkin-diagrams`. But with `tikz`, I am even more lost. I cannot produce code there which explains the idea.

In the end, I want to center the picture and wrap it in a figure environment. I am not sure, if that can be done with the `\begin{dynkinDiagram}...\end{dynkinDiagram}` code sample. As you see from the miniature size the package `dynkin-diagrams` produces, these diagrams are supposed to be used inline. But I want a real figure here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
\def\a{1}
\tikzset{dynkin/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=2mm}}
\path
(0,0)      node[dynkin] (N1) {} 
++(0:\a)   coordinate (A) ++(0:\a) coordinate (B)
++(0:\a)   node[dynkin] (N2) {} 
++(0:2*\a) node[dynkin] (N3) {} +(-90:.5) node{$\beta\perp\alpha+\gamma$}
++(0:2*\a) node[dynkin] (N4) {} +(-90:.5) node{$\gamma$};

\draw[dashed] (A)--(B);
\draw (N1)--(A) (B)--(N2)--(N3)--(N4);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5mm},blue,thick]
(N2.center)--(N1.center) node[midway,below=6mm]{$\alpha'$};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5mm},blue,thick]
(N1.center)--(N3.center) node[midway,above=6mm]{$\alpha$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is exactly what I wanted to achieve. I will study your code and hope I can learn to do it myself in the future. I will acknowledge your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

[image: The two Dynkin diagrams on top of one another]
To compare your code with mine:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[edge length=2cm, edge/.style={ultra thick}, root radius=.2cm]{A}{o.ooo}
\node[below=.2cm] at (root 3) {$\beta\perp\alpha+\gamma$}; 
\node[below=.2cm] at (root 4) {$\gamma$}; 
\end{dynkinDiagram}

\begin{dynkinDiagram}[indefinite edge/.style={ultra thick,densely dashed},o/.style={ultra thick,fill=white,draw=black},edge length=2cm, edge/.style={ultra thick}, root radius=.2cm]{A}{o.ooo}
\node[below=.2cm] at (root 3) {$\beta\perp\alpha+\gamma$}; 
\node[below=.2cm] at (root 4) {$\gamma$}; 
\dynkinBrace*[\alpha]{1}{3}
\dynkinBrace[\alpha']{1}{2}
\end{dynkinDiagram}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! For this problem, I prefer the appearance of the tikz solution. For other problems, the cramped style may be more suitable. The corresponding code for `dynkin-diagrams` will be certainly useful.